# Can't mount, open or list external HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I can't format my hard drive. I think I have formatted it with EXT4 some months ago and secured it with LUKS.
`dmesg` gives me this:

```
[  105.101317] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  105.122022] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=55ae, bcdDevice=30.00
[  105.122024] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  105.122025] usb 2-1: Product: Extreme 55AE
[  105.122026] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  105.122027] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 323132364750343032353932
[  105.126494] scsi host1: uas
[  112.053699] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Extreme 55AE     3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  112.054516] scsi 1:0:0:1: Enclosure         SanDisk  SES Device       3000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  112.054951] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  112.055018] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[  112.055079] ses 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 13
[  112.055190] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[  112.055193] ses 1:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[  112.089832] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

fdisk -l /dev/sda shows this:
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No medium found

[image]

Are there options I can try? Or is this hard drive broken?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the file system or LUKS if you just want to re-format it. It's either the drive itself or the enclosure that failed, the error messages are quite clear.

Comment: mmh okay thank you. I think I will buy a new one. Dont know what I can do. Cant also format it under windows

Comment: *Cant also format it under windows* Obviously if it's an hardware problem.

Comment: @otto As a last resort, you may disassemble it and get the SATA/NVMe drive inside and try it with another enclosure (or directly attach it to some machine).

Comment: The above is a great suggestion. More often than not what fails is the interface, not the actual drive.